# How to change placeholder color in UITextField on tvOS, so that the change is kept and it does not revert back to its default placeholder state?

Tags: uitextfield, tvos

How to change placeholder color in UITextField on tvOS, so that the change is kept and it does not revert back to its default placeholder state?

In viewDidLoad() I have added the following:

```
self.txfUsername?.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Email", attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red:1.0, green:1.0, blue:1.0, alpha:1.0), NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name:"GothamBook", size:38.0)!])
```

So at first the placeholder color is white, however when it looses focus it reverts back to its default state.

How to keep the change of the placeholder color?

Comment: You probably need to set the attributed string for its `.Normal` state: [UIControlState](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState).

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks, however I don't see any possibility to configure the UITextField for a state. Maybe your first thought was that it may work like UIButton.

Comment: @tommagellancook I found one solution which worked in my case. I have the updated the placeholder font colour in the main thread, in focus delegate method. Please try at your end, if it works with you.

Comment: Anybody figure this out yet?

Answer (score 12):

Basically, need to update again the properties in **didUpdateFocus** in the main thread

```
 override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext,
                        with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.emailTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: emailTitle,

                                                                       attributes:  [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white])
        self.passwordTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: passwordTitle,

                                                                          attributes:  [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks the main queue call fixed my issue

Comment: Don't forget to add `super.didUpdateFocus(in: context, with: coordinator)` to retain the highlight animation.

Comment: Not sure if it's specifically because I'm doing this for iOS vs tvOS but `didUpdateFocus` was never getting called. I put the same logic inside `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and used `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` with a 0.01 second delay and it worked just fine.